# using pairwise pmin() on two list of a list

Tags: r

so I have two list with similar size like the code below:

```
a <- list(1,2,3,4)
b <- list(6,7,8,9)
c <- list(10,11,12,13)
all <- list(a,b,c)

a1 <- list(12,13,115,90)
b1 <- list(60,70,80,09)
c1 <- list(100,110,120,130)
all1 <- list(a1,b1,c1)
```

and i am trying to use the **pmax()** to calculate the max values between those two list but I keep getting error like below:

```
Error in mmm < each : comparison of these types is not implemented
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a nested `list`.  We can `unlist`, get the `pmax` and `relist`

```
relist(pmax(unlist(all), unlist(all1)), skeleton = all)
```

---

or do a nested `Map`

```
Map(function(x, y) Map(pmax, x, y), all, all1)
```

Comment: that did the job thank you! but can you advice me on what should i do if i want to know if it belongs to a or a1 for each value in a? like [1][1] [1] 12 belongs to a1?

Comment: @DON_DON The easier is `v1 <- unlist(all); v2 <- unlist(all1); out <- pmax(v1, v2); `out == v1` returns TRUE or FALSE. if it is FALSE, then it should come from v2